# SampleSort with MPI implementation in C, uninitialized warnings in code

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I have this piece of code (it's a samplesort algorithm with MPI in C ) which I am trying to understand but since don't know much about C I got stuck, I searched each part individually but got a bit confused.
My understanding was that malloc shows where in the heap(=memory?) to save and we multiply our given numbers by the user with the sizeofint which is 4 bytes so now we have a correct allocation of memory and we cast it I guess? Though at the above line of code
NoofElements are also initialized as an int (does not atoi makes the string that is argv[1](https://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/%7Edheerajb/MPI/codes/day-3/c/samplesort.c) which equals to first-line input by the user? ) So why do we need to cast it again?:

```
NoofElements = atoi(argv[1]);

Input = (int*)malloc(NoofElements * sizeof(int));
```

Both Input and NoofElemnts are used after in the code, but it shows a warning that they are uninitialized.
Also, some other which I don't really get.

[The link to the full code](https://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/%7Edheerajb/MPI/codes/day-3/c/samplesort.c)

My Warnings:
[image]

Comment: So this is Visual Studio?

Comment: In VS, you can right-click on the warnings and copy them to the clip-board. Then [edit] your post to include the pasted text. I usually paste it to notepad or my code editor and clean it up a bit first. Read [ask] and please don't post images of text. Post an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, if your file has the default `.cpp` file extension, the code is treated as if it is C++. If it's a `.c` extension, then the file can be interpreted as C code, with the caveat that they stopped trying to keep up with C standards, in favor of C++ development, long ago. But I did just confirm, that if it's a C file, the VS 2019 environment won't require the cast as would be required in C++.

In C, casting the return value of malloc is not required. [It's also a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3150445).

---

Getting to your question:

```
NoofElements = atoi(argv[1]); // argv[1] can be NULL.
```

Just because the program expects an argument on the command line, doesn't mean the user will always provide one.

Comment: That's why I get the warnings because of the not support of C?